# SMTP Scrip Task is changing attachments path

Tags: ssis, smtp, attachment

I have developed an SSIS package that uses a fully qualified path for attaching a file to an smtp component. The attachment line looks like this:

Attachment attach = new Attachment("\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx");

But whenever I execute the package on my local I get the following error:

Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx'.

Why is c: being prepended to my attachment which is causing the error?

This used to work until a couple of days ago but without any changes it is failing now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: double backslash for a servername

Comment: also use the @"\\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx"

Comment: Thank you KeithL. The \\ worked but had to put \\ for each level of the folder. Can you help me understand why the need for double \?  Also, I didn't seem to need the @ but why did you recommend that?  Thanks again!

Comment: \ is an escape character in c# for example \t means tab and \\ means \. @"" will ignore escapes so you don't have to double them.

Comment: Hey Keith - thanks for your insight. It's been a while since I've developed anything so appreciate your taking the time to help me. So I changed the attachments line to what is below and it works fine. But whenever I deploy to production I'm still getting the C: prepended to my attachment string and it's failing.  For what it's worth I tried using the \\ w/out the @ as well.                                                                 
Attachment attach = new Attachment(@"\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx");

Comment: Here's the error message I'm receiving whenever I execute this in production after it's deployed. Email Report Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx. Also, for what it's worth this job is set up in production via sql server agent with a Run As an AD account that access to that share.

Comment: Attachment attach = new Attachment(@"\\server\sharedfolder\ssis\processes\labelprinting\LabelsToPrint.xlsx");

Comment: it would need to look like this without @. Attachment attach = new Attachment("\\\\server\\sharedfolder\\ssis\\processes\\labelprinting\\LabelsToPrint.xlsx");

Comment: That worked Keith. Really appreciate your help.